# How to efficiently upload multiple files to Azure blobs from .NET Core Web API?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

I am having the following piece of code inside an API Controller that uploads multiple files to Azure Blob storage for a specific user/session.

This is the snippet in question and the platform is ASP.NET Core 3.1.:

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
    if (file != null)
    {

        if (file.FileName == "")
        {
            // Do some work
        }

        string path = pathPrefix + file.FileName;

        await _blobsService.UploadFileBlobAsync(path, file);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

From my understanding, each call to `await _blobsService.UploadFileBlobAsync(path, file);` is blocking until the file has been uploaded and we move forward to the next file.

I have three questions about this.

1. While you would expect that files are uploaded sequentially, from
   the Azure Portal Application insights End-to-end transactions it
   seems that certain files are uploaded *at the same time* as in the
   picture below?

   [image]
2. What is the best way to gain speed in terms of HTTP request performance (i.e., response time)? Should I fire the UploadFile method for all files and then wait for all to complete, or should I use `Parallel`?
3. If firing all the requests in parallel is the solution, would that mean that Azure Blob Storage would get to a point where many HTTP requests to the upload endpoint would cripple the resources for other clients?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try approach described by Microsoft? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-scalable-app-upload-files

Comment: I am checking it out, in fact, I think it goes to a greater length than what I imagined, for example, I have multiple files that are small in size few KBs each. Also, I am not using the UploadFromFileAsync but rather the UploadAsync passing a MemoryStream. Yet, this does not answer my 1st question, as to why I see concurrent uploads on the application insights.

Comment: Also, the approach described by Microsoft involves the legacy Azure.SDK (v11). In V12 there seems to not exist a UploadFromFileAsync function.

Comment: What is `UploadFileBlobAsync`? Googling returns no docs, only blog posts with methods named `UploadFileBlobAsync`. If that were an SDK or library class, I'd expect that the author already does what you want, uploading multiple blocks concurrently before finalizing the blob

Comment: [BlobClient.UploadAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient.uploadasync?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_BlobClient_UploadAsync_System_IO_Stream_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobUploadOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) itself does this, configured through the [BulkUploadOptions.TransferOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobuploadoptions.transferoptions?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobUploadOptions_TransferOptions) setting

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It is an internal service and it does not do what I want. The method simply uploads a single file by MemoryStream with the function UploadAsync you referred to. This is why I was looking at a concurrent solution in the first place. If you notice my snippet above, there is a simple for-loop now. Thanks for replying in any case.

Comment: That's not what I asked. If `UploadFileBlobAsync` calls `BlobClient.UploadAsync`, most likely the file is *already* uploaded in parallel. So what does `UploadFileBlobAsync` do? What happens if you upload a single large file? Do you still see the concurrent upload of blocks?

Comment: Instead of AppInsights it's better to use Fiddler to see what your client is actually doing. I suspect you'll see multiple concurrent operations, even for a single file. *Assuming your bandwidth allows it* you could increase performance by modifying TransferOptions.

Comment: *On the other hand* if you have multiple small files it's better to execute multiple uploads concurrently but *not* through `Parallel.ForEach`. That's only meant for data parallelism, and doesn't work with async operations - in-memory processing doesn't block. Use an ActionBlock with a DOP>1 instead

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. To answer your first comment, yes it does call that function. But it takes only one file at a time. Yet, from the screenshot I posted you see that for example that the first three files are uploaded in parallel. In my scenario, the client uploads multiple smalls files around 1KB per file ranging from 6 to 100 files, depending on the use case.

Comment: Instead of writing your own code, have you considered using the [Data Movement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-data-movement-library) library? I haven't checked the code yet but the examples look like AWS's TransferUtility, which also uses parallel loading *and* verifies hashes, takes care of concurrency issues etc. Quite often, the best code is the one you don't write and libraries often include steps and verifications one wouldn't think of.

Comment: No, not really. Because then, I will have to change a lot more than the upload function and maybe it is unnecessary work. Thanks for your replies.